# Migrating from JBOSS-ESB to SWITCHYARD

Tags: jboss-esb, switchyard

**strong text**Hello Guys,

I need some help here. we are migrating from **jboss-esb** framework to **switchyard**. When i copy my code in switchyard i have loads of errors is coming. If anyone know about **switchyard**.

Thanks in Advance
Hemanth

Comment: Please be more specific: share your code and the errors you get, so that they can be addressed.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, SwitchYard is not a complete compatible framework with JBoss ESB. It's not something you can copy and run your legacy applications on without modifying them. You need an amount of efforts to "migrate" your applications to SwitchYard. Check the list of migration advices in the below link for more detail:
https://github.com/windup/soa-migration/tree/master/advice

With that said, unfortunately upstream SwitchYard development is not active any longer. If you are looking for a lightweight integration framework that can run on JBoss EAP / WildFly, then I'd recommend to look at WildFly Camel:
http://wildfly-extras.github.io/wildfly-camel/

Apache Camel has an active community and most of your integration requirements can be migrated to it; at least it should be as easy (or hard) as migration to SwitchYard.

Comment: Thanks your info Sato. Unfortunately this is client requirement. I will share my code here if anyone have idea suggest me .